# Listfragment Crashes pretty basic application every time

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am currently trying to work with Android ActionBar Sherlock on my Nexus One running Gingerbread 2.3.4.
I try to develop a FragmentList which enables me to create a Menu in this activity. 
The menu should now consist out of "item1 - item4" However sometime later I want the menu to consists out of a custom made list.

However, whenever I try to execute my App it force closes for some reason or another.

This is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="0dip"
android:background="@drawable/bg">
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Hauptmenü"
android:background="@drawable/custom_bg_title"
android:padding="5dip"
android:gravity="center"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:height="30px"
 />

<fragment class="com.w..TitlesFragment"
        android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

This is the codefile of the activity

```
package com.;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.support.v4.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.view.SubMenu;
import android.support.v4.view.Window;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class wcw_realActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnItemClickListener {


private static final String[] items ={"item1","item2","item3","item4"};
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    SubMenu subMenu1 = menu.addSubMenu("Action Item");
        subMenu1.add("Sample");
        subMenu1.add("Menu");
        subMenu1.add("Items");

    MenuItem subMenu1Item = subMenu1.getItem();
        subMenu1Item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_title_share_default);
        subMenu1Item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);          

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);        
    setContentView(R.layout.main);                       
}   

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Log.i("FragmentList", "Item clicked: "+ id);
}

public static class TitlesFragment extends ListFragment {
    boolean mDualPane;
    int mCurCheckPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedState);

        // Populate list with our static array of titles.
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                items));

        if (savedState != null) {
            // Restore last state for checked position.
            mCurCheckPosition = savedState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
        Log.i("FragmentList", "Item clicked: "+ id);
    }

}
```

}

I suspect that I initialize the fragment on a bad way - which would probably explain that the App crashes every time.

When I exclude the "fragment" Tag out of my app it works just fine.

It would be great if someone knows a solution for that particular problem.

Here is the logfile

Comment: Please post the stacktrace from your logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) (or any other `Fragment`) is not available in Gingerbread by default. You might be compiling against Honeycomb which is why it compiles but crashes when run. Use the [compatibility package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) to use Fragments in older versions of Android. Also, make sure you have your `minSdkVersion` set to the right one.

If you're already using the compatibility package, maybe you are not including it correctly (since the `ListFragment` class cannot be found)?